# Android license status unknown and cannot be solved

Tags: android, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTb5r.png)

I am not able to run flutter apps because the error keeps popping up in the cmd section that Android license unknown. I've even tried updating android studio, but no help.
Also an error comes but I crossed checked it that the file it asks to delete is already deleted and android sdk manager is already present. I'm copying the errors:

1)**Android license not found error**

X Android license status unknown.
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

2)**Android sdk manager and gradle-wrapper error**

Failed to delete "C:\flutter\bin\cache\downloads\storage.googleapis.com\flutter_infra\gradle-wrapper\fd5c1f2c013565a3bea56ada6df9d2b8e96d56aa\gradle-wrapper.tgz". Please delete manually. FileSystemException:
Cannot delete file, path = 'C:\flutter\bin\cache\downloads\storage.googleapis.com\flutter_infra\gradle-wrapper\fd5c1f2c013565a3bea56ada6df9d2b8e96d56aa\gradle-wrapper.tgz' (OS Error: The process cannot access
the file because it is being used by another process.
, errno = 32)
Android sdkmanager tool not found (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

Comment: Have you tried to logout and login or restart your system?

Comment: Yes I did but it didn't help.